# How to update and add new records at the same time

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, insert-update, bulk

I have a table that contains over than a million records (products).
Now, daily, I need to either update existing records, and/or add new ones.

Instead of doing it one-by-one (takes couple of hours), I managed to use `SqlBulkCopy` to work with bunch of records and managed to do my inserts in the matter of seconds, but it can handle only new inserts. So I am thinking about creating a new table that contains new records and old records; and then use that temporary table (on the SQL end) to update/add to the main table.

Any advice how can I perform that update?

Comment: Yes, that is how you should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the better ways to handle this is with the [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command in SQL.  Mssqltips has a good [tutorial](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/) on it, it can be a bit trickier to use than some of the other commands.

Also, due to locking you may want to break this up into multiple smaller transactions, unless you know you can tolerate blocking during the update.

Answer (score 0):

We handle this situation in our code in the way you described; we have a temp table, then run an update where the ID in the temp table matches the table to be updated, then run an insert where the ID in the table to be updated is null. We normally do this for updates to library/program settings, though, so it is only run infrequently, on smaller tables. Performance may not be up to par for that many records, or daily runs.

The main "gotcha" I've encountered with this method is that for the update, we did a comparison to make sure at least one of several fields changed before actually running the update. (Our initial reason for this was to avoid overwriting some defaults, which could affect server behavior. Your reason for this might be performance, if your temp table could contain records that haven't actually changed). We encountered a case where we did actually want to update one of the defaults, but our old script didn't catch that. So if you do any comparisons to determine which products you want to update, make sure it is either complete from the start, or document well any fields you don't compare, and why.

Comment: Right now, after a research I stumbled upon `MERGE` in SQL; have you tried that?